# Difference between mq_send and msgsnd

Tags: c, pthreads, message-queue

I am trying to implement a multi-threaded program in C using `pthreads` and wanted to send messages between threads.

While reading online I came across two types of methods.

One is posix Queues which uses functions such as `mq_receive`, `mq_send` and another method `msgrcv`, `msgsnd`.

Also I noticed in mq_send, we can send only character strings and not a custom defined data structure. Is there a way to send a different data structure using mq_send or an alternative function?

Which is the best method to use? And in which case is it best to use these functions?

Comment: If you're interested in these, I recommend you try Unix Domain Sockets instead.  I found that UDS worked better on Linux, and also has the advantage of using the usual socket APIs more similar to TCP and UDP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

POSIX:
`mq_send` and `mq_receive` are POSIX. The POSIX message queues are compared to System V modern, simple and light. It has simple I/O functions and you can only send and receive bytes. In POSIX you have the possibility to send data with a priority. The read function is simple and you can only read the next data. In this case System V can do much more.

However you are able to send complex structs using POSIX message queues too. You have to use unions.

```
struct mydata {
    int i;
    long x;
    // whatever you want
};

union myunion {
    struct mydata;
    char bytes[sizeof(mydata)];
};
```

Now you just have to send your data this way:

```
myunion u;
u.mydata = // struct to send
mq_send(... &u.bytes .....); // access byte sequence of struct
```

System V:
The System V message queue is much more complex. Can can send complex structs and send it with priorities. The receiver can be configured so that you receive only messages with one selected priority or all messages ordered by priority. It has much more capabilities.

I prefer POSIX because it is simple and easy to use. With POSIX you also can register for notification using `mq_notify`. There you get an event if a message is available and you do not need to do polling. In System V you can not do this.

Answer (score 1):

From http://linux.die.net/man/7/mq_overview :

> System V message queues (msgget(2), msgsnd(2), msgrcv(2), etc.) are an older API for exchanging messages between processes. POSIX message queues provide a better designed interface than System V message queues; on the other hand POSIX message queues are less widely available (especially on older systems) than System V message queues.
>
> Linux does not currently (2.6.26) support the use of access control lists (ACLs) for POSIX message queues.

So it depends on how much you value portability to older systems, I guess?

Comment: How about passing a custom data structure using mq_send? I dont think it is possible

Comment: It's possible, provided that you use a cast and properly set the `msg_len` parameter. If you need to pass different custom structures you can think of a header/payload struct.